# Unable to import "LogisticRegression" from sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am getting Import error for LogisticRegression while importing in my code.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LogisticRegression
```

Error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\VSCODE\GIT_Hub\myML\Proj2-FruitSurvey-SimpleClassificationModels\ML-Models.py", line 78, in <module>
from sklearn.model_selection import LogisticRegression
ImportError: cannot import name 'LogisticRegression'
```

I have no issues while loading other modules like

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV,cross_validate
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

I am using python version =3.6.5 
           scikit-learn=0.21.0
           windows 10
           code editor = vscode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in `sklearn.linear_model`, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html